SQLAlchemy engine initialization aborts
I wrote a small Class for database interaction in my application. however any attempt to create an instance of the Class results in the following error
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted

here is the Class definition. I left out other Class methods, as it is the initialization itself causing the error.
class DBService:

  def __init__(self,schema='public'):
    self.username = PG_USERNAME
    self.password = PG_PASSWORD
    self.host     = PG_HOST
    self.port     = PG_PORT
    self.dbname   = PG_DBNAME
    self.schema   = schema

    self.db_string  = f'postgresql://{self.username}:{self.password}@{self.host}:{self.port}/{self.dbname}'      
    self.engine     = create_engine(self.db_string, echo=True,connect_args={"options": "-c timezone=utc"})
    self.engine     = create_engine(
      self.db_string,
      connect_args={ "options": f"-c timezone=Europe/Vienna"}
    )

    result = self.fetch_scalar(f"SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name = '{self.schema}';")
    if not result:
      self.execute(f"CREATE SCHEMA {self.schema};")
      print(f"Schema '{self.schema}' created.")
    self.execute(f"SET search_path TO {schema};")


  def execute(self, sql,params={}):
    with self.engine.connect() as conn:
      trans = conn.begin()
      try:
        if params:
          conn.execute(text(sql), params)
        else:
          conn.execute(text(sql))
        trans.commit()
      except Exception as e:
        raise e

Thanks in advance for your input.
I have no idea whats generating this error.

Turns out all i had to do was install sycopg2-binary
